# Querying Counts on Field Values in a Single Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum, case

I have a single product table with multiple fields which contain user evaluations of various attributes:

```
product  | attr_1_eval   | attr_2_eval   | attr_3_eval
ABC      | Correct       | Incorrect     | Null
DEF      | Incorrect     | Null          | Null
XYZ      | Undetermined  | Null          | Incorrect
123      | Null          | Undetermined  | Correct
456      | Incorrect     | Correct       | Correct
```

I need to write a query which totals up those attribute evaluations across all products (where not null):

```
evaluation  | correct   | incorrect   | undetermined
attr_1      | 1         | 2           | 1
attr_2      | 1         | 1           | 1
attr_3      | 2         | 1           | 0
```

This SQL gets me part way there:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN attr_1_eval = 'Correct' then 1 else 0 END) AS correct,
SUM(CASE WHEN attr_1_eval = 'Incorrect' then 1 else 0 END) AS incorrect,
SUM(CASE WHEN attr_1_eval = 'Undetermined' then 1 else 0 END) AS undetermined,
SUM(CASE WHEN attr_2_eval = 'Correct' then 1 else 0 END) AS correct,
...
FROM product
```

But it doesn't group `attr_1, attr_2..` by rows with error counts in the columns (as in the desired result set above).  I'm using Postgres but help in any flavor of SQL would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do 3 unions?

```
SELECT 
  'attr_1' AS evaluation,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attr_1_eval = 'Correct' then 1 else 0 END) AS correct,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attr_1_eval = 'Incorrect' then 1 else 0 END) AS incorrect,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attr_1_eval = 'Undetermined' then 1 else 0 END) AS undetermined
FROM product
UNION
SELECT 
  'attr_2' AS evaluation,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attr_2_eval = 'Correct' then 1 else 0 END) AS correct,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attr_2_eval = 'Incorrect' then 1 else 0 END) AS incorrect,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attr_2_eval = 'Undetermined' then 1 else 0 END) AS undetermined
FROM product
UNION
SELECT 
  'attr_3' AS evaluation,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attr_3_eval = 'Correct' then 1 else 0 END) AS correct,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attr_3_eval = 'Incorrect' then 1 else 0 END) AS incorrect,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attr_3_eval = 'Undetermined' then 1 else 0 END) AS undetermined
FROM product
```

It's not the most elegant/efficient solution probably but it should get what you want

Comment: I was just gonna post that. The only change that I would do, is to replace the `UNION` with `UNION ALL`, since the static `'attr_1','attr_2','attr_3'` make sure that the records are different

Comment: Worked perfectly in Postgres, including the `UNION All` per @Lamak.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little brute force, and I hate the fact that it scans the table three times, but this does appear to get the desired output.  I'm sorry I don't know PostGres, but this should work in Oracle:

```
select
  Attribute_name,
  Sum (correct) as Correct,
  sum (incorrect) as Incorrect,
  sum (undetermined) as Undetermined
from
  (
  select
    'attr_1' as Attribute_Name,
    decode (attr_1_eval, 'Correct', 1, 0) as correct,
    decode (attr_1_eval, 'Incorrect', 1, 0) as incorrect,
    decode (attr_1_eval, 'Undetermined', 1, 0) as undetermined
  from product
  union all
  select
    'attr_2',
    decode (attr_2_eval, 'Correct', 1, 0),
    decode (attr_2_eval, 'Incorrect', 1, 0),
    decode (attr_2_eval, 'Undetermined', 1, 0)
  from product
  union all
  select
    'attr_3',
    decode (attr_3_eval, 'Correct', 1, 0),
    decode (attr_3_eval, 'Incorrect', 1, 0),
    decode (attr_3_eval, 'Undetermined', 1, 0)
  from product
)
group by Attribute_Name
```